# De Morgan's Law - The answer is with square brackets or without square brackets?

Tags: propositional-calculus

**De Morgan's Law - Propositional Calculus**

Can someone tell me what's the correct way to solve this proposition with De Morgan's Law?

Proposition:
$q \vee ¬[ (p \wedge q) \vee ¬q ]$

[Answers]

Option 1:

> $q \vee ¬(p \wedge q) \wedge q$

Option 2:

> $q \vee [¬(p \wedge q) \wedge q ]$

As you can see, the difference between both is that one of them don't have square brackets "[ ]". So, what's the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second version is correct because you are just applying DeMorgan to the second part.  You can simplify it further, but I don't see that as part of the question.  If the first $q$ were $r$ throughout, it would matter how you grouped the three terms at the end.

Comment: @Arthur:  you are right.  I had noticed that all the clauses were joined by $\vee$ at the start, but missed that it changed at the end, as it should because of DeMorgan

Comment: Ross Millikan, thanks for the observation, I edited it. Thanks again and sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $\land$ as having higher precedence that $\lor$ (just like $\cdot $ has higher precedence than $+$), then 
$$ q \vee (¬(p \wedge q) \wedge q )\equiv q \vee ¬(p \wedge q) \wedge q $$
in the same way as
$$ q + \left((p \cdot q)^2 \cdot q \right)=q + (p \cdot q)^2 \cdot q.$$
If you do not define such precedence, then the extra brackets are needed (as would be differently placed brackets for any alternative interpretation).

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the original expression you can use replacement of variables and rewrite it as $q \vee \neg A$ where A is the expression in braces, because of this idea option 2 is the correct one